# How to use the Illinois Chunker with sentences as input?

Tags: java, nlp

I am trying to use the [Illinois Chunker](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/Chunker) on a per-sentence basis. The *entry point* provided, in a manner of speaking, is the following code snippet:

```
public class ChunksAndPOSTags {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = null;
    try {
        filename = args[0];
        if (args.length > 1) throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("usage: java edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.lbj.chunk.ChunksAndPOSTags <input file>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Chunker chunker = new Chunker();
    Parser parser = new PlainToTokenParser(
        new WordSplitter(new SentenceSplitter(filename)));
        String previous = "";
        for (Word w = (Word) parser.next(); w != null; w = (Word) parser.next()) {
            String prediction = chunker.discreteValue(w);
            if (prediction.startsWith("B-") ||
                prediction.startsWith("I-") &&
                !previous.endsWith(prediction.substring(2)))
                System.out.print("[" + prediction.substring(2) + " ");
            System.out.print("(" + w.partOfSpeech + " " + w.form + ") ");
            if (!prediction.equals("O") &&
                (w.next == null                                 || 
                 chunker.discreteValue(w.next).equals("O")      || 
                 chunker.discreteValue(w.next).startsWith("B-") ||
                 !chunker.discreteValue(w.next).endsWith(prediction.substring(2))))
                System.out.print("] ");
            if (w.next == null)
                System.out.println();
            previous = prediction;
        }
    }
}
```

How can we modify the above to chunk **one sentence at a time** instead of giving a text file?

Comment: I had no idea what the [Illinois Chunker](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/Chunker) was. Thankfully, it's not in the same realm as a Cleveland Steamer. Thanks for broadening my horizons.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own SentenceParser that would just return your string  (your 'one sentence at a time').

Below is the sample code

```
import LBJ2.parse.Parser;
import LBJ2.nlp.Sentence;

public class FakeSentenceSplitter implements Parser {

    private final String sentenceText;

    public FakeSentenceSplitter(String sentenceText) {
        super();
        this.sentenceText = sentenceText;
    }

    public Object next() {
        return new Sentence(sentenceText);
    }

    public void reset() {
    }

    public void close() {
    }
}
```

If you don't already use LBJ2 package, it can be downloaded [here](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/download_view/LBJ).

After that you should use your new Sentence splitter in this line:

```
Parser parser = new PlainToTokenParser(
        new WordSplitter(new FakeSentenceSplitter(filename)));
```